# How to reverse a name from prompt | String to Array reversed

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, reverse

I started learning Javascript recently, and as a little challenge I tried to create a program where a prompt asks for a name, and then the program prints the name out in reverse. My thinking was as follows:

```
var name = prompt("What is your name?");
name = new Array(name.length);
name.reverse();
document.write(name);
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: You lost the original contents of `name`; you just overwrote it with an array of size `name.length`.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the string to an array, reverse it, join it back up:

```
s.split('').reverse().join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

To start, the array knows nothing about the string's characters.  You're just creating an null-filled array the same length.

A correct way to convert a string to array uses `splice`:

```
name = Array.prototype.slice.apply(name);
```

`slice` is an array method that returns a section of an array.  When you don't pass any arguments, it clones the array.  Conveniently, it works for non-arrays and produces an array.

[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is a way of calling a function on an arbitrary object.  It lets us call an array method on a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = "yourname";
var myFunction = function () {
var s = name;
return s.split('').reverse().join('');
}
myFunction();
```

Comment: You should add some sort of explanation to your answer, not just code. The question was "what's wrong with this code?", so adding a bit of text is more what the OP was asking for as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var fullName = prompt(" What is your full name"); 
    document.getElementById("fn").innerHTML = fullName.toUpperCase();


    document.getElementById("len").innerHTML = fullName.length;


function back() {

    return fullName.split('').reverse().join('');
}
document.getElementById("back").innerHTML=back();
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score -1):

Reverse isn't an official String object method.

Althought, you can prototype it.

http://www.bytemycode.com/snippets/snippet/400/

Comment: He's calling the reverse method on Array

Comment: Which is why @needtoknow is calling reverse on an array